# Inverse of a matrix exponential, ${(e^{At})}^{-1} = {e^{-At}}$

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

Consider the matrix exponential
$$
e^{At} = \frac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
      -e^{-t} + 5e^{3t} &  e^{-t} - e^{3t} \\
     -5e^{-t} + 5e^{3t} & 5e^{-t} - e^{3t}
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

And
$$
{(e^{At})}^{-1} =  {e^{-At}}
$$

What does that identity mean?  Can I just multiply the exponent by $-1$ to find  $e^{-At}$?

Comment: Yes. (...and some more characters)

Comment: Does that identity rule also apply to a symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If two square matrices $A$ and $B$ *commute* ($AB = BA$), then
$$
e^A e^B = e^{A+B}.
$$

Now, $A$ and $-A$ always commute, so
$$
e^A e^{-A} = e^{A+(-A)} = e^{0} = I.
$$

This shows that
$$
\left( e^A \right)^{-1} = e^{-A}.
$$

Comment: I understand but how does that imply $e^{-At} =  \frac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
      -e^{t} + 5e^{-3t} &  e^{t} - e^{-3t} \\
     -5e^{t} + 5e^{-3t} & 5e^{t} - e^{-3t}
  \end{bmatrix}
$?

Can i just switch all $e^t$ with $e^{-t}$ in $e^{At}$ to get  $e^{-At}$? if yes, why?

Answer (score 8):

If you know $e^{At}$, then to get $e^{-At} = e^{A(-t)}$, you just replace $t$ with $-t$ in the formula for $e^{At}$.  The other answer is correct, but this answers the question you posed in your comment.

Comment: I see. Thanks !